# How to find header elements in html panel and add event to header to hide p tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with my JavaScript.  I'm trying to write a script to find all header elements inside a container and add a click event to the headers to hide p tags.

```
Javascript 
$(function(){
$("dnn_htmlPan1").find(":header").click(function(){
        $("dnn_htmlPan1").find("p").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Html

```
<div id="dnn_htmlPan1" class="htmlPan">
    <h2>EXPLORE</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jQuery selectors are wrong:

`#` is for id:

```
$("#dnn_htmlPan1").find(":header").click(function(){
        $("#dnn_htmlPan1").find("p").slideToggle("slow");
        // or 
        // $(this).parent().find("p").slideToggle("slow");
        // or 
        // $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

---

`:header` is correct:

### `:header` Selector

> Description: Selects all elements that are **headers**, like h1, h2, h3 and so on.

[Read more in documentation](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/)

Comment: You may want to make the inner logic relative to the clicked header: `$(this).find("p").slideToggle("slow");`. +1 regardless

Comment: Maybe `$(this).parrent()`, because `$(this)` will be the clicked header. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$("dnn_htmlPan1").find(":header").click(function(){
```

To:

```
$("#dnn_htmlPan1").find(":header").click(function() {
```

You forgot the `#` to symbolize you're searching for an ID

Comment: In this case, `:header` is appropriate - he wants to find all header elements.

Comment: @tymeJV I also found it now. ;-)

Comment: just wanted to add that in this case its better to use class selector on all panels other then that good answer +1

Comment: @Johnツ -- Need to stop assuming selectors that I haven't seen are wrong, haha.